# AndroidView always on top in Box in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

This is my code

```
        setContent {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
                AndroidView(factory = { unityView }) //this view is UnityPlayer
                //other view
                Button() // this Button is below AndroidView
            }
        }
```

The AndroidView is always on top

Comment: you want button below the androidView?

Comment: @AgentP I want button above AndroidView

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a row or column modifier before using the Box

```
@Composable
fun AlignInColomn() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(150.dp)
            
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
                AndroidView(factory = { unityView })       
            }
        //other view
        Button() 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create by  using these line of codes:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
  Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
    AndroidView(factory = { unityView })
  }

  Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().align(Alignment.BottomCenter)){
    // Place all other view here...
    Button() // Now Button is above the AndroidView
  }

}
```